# REST api and multiple clusters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest

I have a Node.js REST api running in multiple clusters, now I'm looking for a way to assign specific endpoints to specific clusters.

For instance, I have the following endpoints:

- GET /api/data
- GET /api/users
- POST /api/users

Now because `GET /api/data` runs some heavy mongo queries, I don't want to run this in the same clusters as the other endpoints.
This query usually takes around 30 seconds to run, depending on traffic, I do not want to obstruct other users trying to make different API calls.

A few questions I have:

1. Will this actually help my API
2. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Why not shard your mongo database and let it take care of routing queries to different hosts?

It would be a lot simpler than having some sort of load balancer distributing calls to your api endpoints.